# How do I pass the '%' symbol as a command line argument (argv) in Visual Studio 2015 Debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, command-line-arguments

I am using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015, C++.

If I pass a command line argument containing a '%' symbol, I get different results when I run it from the command line compared to when I pass it using `Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments`. The former gibes me what I expect.

To demonstrate, I used this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{   
    int count;  
    cout << "\nCommand-line arguments:\n";  
    for (count = 0; count < argc; count++) {
        cout << "  argv[" << count << "]   " << argv[count] << "\n";
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Compiled as TestArgs and run from the command line, I get:

```
D:\TestArgs\x64\Debug>TestArgs.exe test %02 smiley

Command-line arguments:
  argv[0]   TestArgs.exe
  argv[1]   test
  argv[2]   %02
  argv[3]   smiley

D:\TestArgs\x64\Debug>
```

But when I use Visual Studio Debugging with the same arguments, I get:

```
Command-line arguments:
  argv[0]   D:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestArgs\x64\Debug\TestArgs.exe
  argv[1]   test
  argv[2]   ☻
  argv[3]   smiley
```

That is, the %02 becomes a "smiley". How do I avoid this behavior? Can I be sure that once compiled, the % will be interpreted as a % when run from the command line?

Sorry if this has been asked before; it's not easy to search for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did try that, and got %☻. It was my first thought (though couldn't find anything to confirm it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to replace `%` with `%25` because `%` is interpreted as [escape sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: Yep, this is it. Weird that I've never come across this before. Thanks.